# Authentication of Cloud Automation manager ReST API requests

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-automation-manager

I am trying to use IBM CAM's ReST API but I get `401 Unauthorised` error. How to I generate the authorization token to authorize to access the resources?

Answer (score 0):

### Get access token from Bluemix

You can do a POST to:

```
https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token
```

with headers:

```
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Authorization : Basic Y2Y6
Accept : application/json
```

and body:

```
grant_type=password&username={yourusername}&password={yourpassword}
```

this will return you JSON containing an `access_token`

Copy that access token and you can use it in your calls to Cloud Automation Manager (CAM) APIs as a bearer token

### Use token with Cloud Automation Manager

Sample API call to CAM to retrieve a list of deployments (Stacks):

```
https://cam-proxy-ng.ng.bluemix.net/cam/api/v1/Stacks?cloudOE_spaceGuid={spaceuuid}&ace_orgGuid={orguuid}&tenantId={tenantuuid}
```

Where you can get `spaceuuid, orguuid and tenantuuid` from your browser cookies under cam-proxy-dev.ng.bluemix.net Note: remove any "%22" from the data at the beginning and end of the uuid of the cookie data.

with headers:

```
Authorization : bearer <accesstoken>
```

You can see more APIs listed here 
https://cam-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/#/

Comment: I could get the token but coudn't get response for GET API `https://cam-proxy-ng.ng.bluemix.net/cam/api/v1/cloudconnections` with `Authorization=Bearer ASDJHLD....` header. I got 401.

Comment: Hello, at the end of the API have you also included the spaceuuid, orguuid and tenantId?  like this

/cloudconnections?cloudOE_spaceGuid={spaceuuid}&ace_orgGuid={orguuid}&tenantId={tenantuuid}


Note: you can retrieve these uuids from your browser cookies when logged into the UI.

Are you seeing an error? or perhaps no response?

Comment: note: I think I also see a space in your cloudconnecti‌​ons between the i and o when I copy/paste it (could just be how it was pasted on this site)

Comment: I do not see these cookies in the browser cache. I am using Chrome browser.